# VSCode working with remote Jupyter server (on Paperspace Gradient )

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am confused about how to do remote development with VSCode and a remote Juputer server.

Here are the things that I did:

1. Get a URL for the remote Jupyter Kernel on Paperspace. See [documentation](https://docs.paperspace.com/gradient/notebooks/notebooks-remote-kernel/) here. Note that if I put this URL into a web browser, it will open up JupterLabs and I can see all the remote files, etc.
2. In VSCode, go to the command palette, select Jupyter: specify Jupyter server for connections

After these steps, I can create a new Jupyter notebook, connect to the remote kernel and do development.

But there are several problems:

1. I am not able to see the Jupyter notebooks on the remote file system. Every time I have to create a brand new notebook.
2. When I save the notebook, it is saved on my local disk. I don't know how to save it to the remote file system.

Can someone give me some hint about doing remote development with Jupyter notebook correctly?

Note that this is not remote development with ssh, with which I have better luck, but Paperspace Gradient does not support ssh.

Comment: Did you manage to work it out? I have the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

From this GIF there is a separate URI for getting a remote kernel to the one in your address bar. Try using this to connect.

[image: GIF showing the location to acquire remote kernel link]

Comment: It connects fine and I was able to see remote files with `!ls`, but I couldn't open or save to remote files.